# Implementing Directed and Undirected Graph in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, graph

I am learning C++ and I decided to implement a Directed and UnDirected graph.  (I haven't learned how to do inheritance yet, so they are distinct classes.) I have not handled any error cases (i.e. trying to remove a vertex that doesn't exist.)

I am interested in any comments/criticisms of my approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Graph;
class Edge;
class Vertex;

class Edge {
  int weight;
  Vertex * vertex1;
  Vertex * vertex2;
public:
  int getWeight() const {return weight;}
  Vertex* getV1() const {return vertex1;}
  Vertex* getV2() const {return vertex2;}
  void setWeight(int w){weight=w;}
  void setV1(Vertex * v){vertex1=v;}
  void setV2(Vertex * v){vertex2=v;}
  Edge(int w, Vertex* v1, Vertex* v2){weight=w;vertex1=v1;vertex2=v2;}
};

class Vertex {
  string label;
  vector<Edge *> edgesLeavingMe;
  bool visited;
public:
  string getLabel() const {return label;}

  vector<Edge*> getEdges()const{return edgesLeavingMe;}

  Edge * getEdgeTo(string d){
    for (vector<Edge *>::iterator it = edgesLeavingMe.begin(); it != edgesLeavingMe.end(); ++it){
      if ((*it)->getV2()->getLabel()==d){
    return (*it);
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
  void setVisited(bool v){visited=v;}
  bool getVisited() {return visited;}
  void addEdge(Edge * e){edgesLeavingMe.push_back(e);}
  void removeEdge(Edge * e){edgesLeavingMe.erase(remove(edgesLeavingMe.begin(),edgesLeavingMe.end(),e),edgesLeavingMe.end());}

  void removeEdgeTo(string l){
    Edge * e = getEdgeTo(l);
    removeEdge(e);
  }

  Vertex(string l){label=l; visited=false;}
};

class Graph {
  vector<Edge*> edges;
  map<string, Vertex*> vertices;
public:
  Vertex * addVertex(string label){
    Vertex * v = new Vertex(label);
    vertices[label]=v;
    return v;
  }
  Edge * addEdge(int w, string from, string to);
  void removeEdge(string from, string to);
  Vertex * getVertexWithlabel(string l);
  void removeVertex(string l);
};




class UnDirectedGraph {
  vector<Edge*> edges;
  map<string, Vertex*> vertices;
public:
  Vertex *  addVertex(string label){
    Vertex * v = new Vertex(label);
    vertices[label]=v;
    return v;
  }

  map<string, Vertex*> getVertices(){return vertices;}
  vector<Edge*> getEdges(){return edges;}

  Edge * addEdge(int w, string from, string to){

    if (vertices.find(from) != vertices.end() && vertices.find(to) != vertices.end()){
      Vertex * vfrom = vertices.find(from)->second;
      Vertex * vto = vertices.find(to)->second;
      Edge * e = new Edge(w,vfrom,vto);
      (*vfrom).addEdge(e);
      (*vto).addEdge(e);
      edges.push_back(e);
      return e;
    }
    else{
      //needt o handle case where vertices did not exist.
      return 0;
    }
  }

  Edge * getEdge(string from, string to){
    if (vertices.find(from) != vertices.end() && vertices.find(to) != vertices.end()){
      Vertex * v1 = vertices.find(from)->second;
      Vertex* v2 = vertices.find(to)->second;
      Edge * e = (*v1).getEdgeTo(to);
      return e;
    }
    else {
      //need to handle case where vertices did not exist.
      return 0;
    }
  }

  void removeEdge(string from, string to){
    Edge * e = getEdge(from,to);
    if (e != 0){
      edges.erase(remove(edges.begin(),edges.end(),e),edges.end());
      (*e).getV1()->removeEdge(e);
      (*e).getV2()->removeEdge(e);
    }
    //handle case where edge did not exist?
  }

  Vertex * getVertexWithLabel(string l){
    if (vertices.find(l) != vertices.end())
      return vertices.find(l)->second;
    else
      return 0;
  }

  void removeVertex(string l){
    Vertex * v = getVertexWithLabel(l);
    if (v != 0){
      vector<Edge *> edges = getVertexWithLabel(l)->getEdges();

      for (vector<Edge *>::iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); ++it){
    string from = (*it)->getV1()->getLabel();
    string to = (*it)->getV2()->getLabel();
    removeEdge(from,to);
      }
      vertices.erase(l);
    }
    else {
      //Need to handle case where vertex does not exist.
     }
  }

  vector<Vertex *> whereCanIGo(Vertex * v)
  {
    vector<Vertex *> destinations;
    vector<Edge *> edges = v->getEdges();
    for (vector<Edge *>::const_iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); ++it) {
      if ((*it)->getV1() != v){
    destinations.push_back((*it)->getV1());
      }
      if ((*it)->getV2() !=v) {
    destinations.push_back((*it)->getV2());
      }
    }      
    destinations.push_back(v);
    return destinations;
  }

};

class DirectedGraph {
  vector<Edge*> edges;
  map<string, Vertex*> vertices;
public:
  Vertex *  addVertex(string label){
    Vertex * v = new Vertex(label);
    vertices[label]=v;
    return v;
  }
  map<string, Vertex*> getVertices(){return vertices;}
  vector<Edge*> getEdges(){return edges;}

  Edge * addEdge(int w, string from, string to){

    if (vertices.find(from) != vertices.end() && vertices.find(to) != vertices.end()){
      Vertex * vfrom = vertices.find(from)->second;
      Vertex * vto = vertices.find(to)->second;
      Edge * e = new Edge(w,vfrom,vto);
      (*vfrom).addEdge(e);
      edges.push_back(e);
      return e;
    }
    else{
      //handle case where vertcies did not exist.
      return 0;
    }
  }

  Edge * getEdge(string from, string to){
    if (vertices.find(from) != vertices.end() && vertices.find(to) != vertices.end()){
      Vertex * v1 = vertices.find(from)->second;
      Vertex* v2 = vertices.find(to)->second;
      Edge * e = (*v1).getEdgeTo(to);
      return e;
    }
    else {
      return 0;
    }
  }


  void removeEdge(string from, string to){
    Edge * e = getEdge(from,to);
    if (e != 0){
      edges.erase(remove(edges.begin(),edges.end(),e),edges.end());
      (*e).getV1()->removeEdge(e);
    }
  }

  Vertex * getVertexWithLabel(string l){
    if (vertices.find(l) != vertices.end())
      return vertices.find(l)->second;
    else
      return 0;
  }

  void removeVertex(string l){
    Vertex * v = getVertexWithLabel(l);
    if (v != 0){
      vector<Edge *> edges = getVertexWithLabel(l)->getEdges();

      for (vector<Edge *>::iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); ++it){
    string from = (*it)->getV1()->getLabel();
    string to = (*it)->getV2()->getLabel();
    removeEdge(from,to);
      }
      vertices.erase(l);
    }
    else {
      //handle case where vertex did not exist.
    }
  }

  vector<Vertex *> whereCanIGo(Vertex * v)
  {
    vector<Vertex *> destinations;
    vector<Edge *> edges = v->getEdges();
    for (vector<Edge *>::const_iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); ++it) {
      if ((*it)->getV2() !=v) {
    destinations.push_back((*it)->getV2());
      }
    }      
    destinations.push_back(v);
    return destinations;
  }

};



template <class T> 
void printGraph(T * t){

  map<string,Vertex*> vertices = t->getVertices();

  for (map<string, Vertex*>::iterator it = vertices.begin(); it != vertices.end(); ++it){
    cout << it->first <<": ";
    vector<Edge *> edges = it->second->getEdges();
    for (vector<Edge *>::iterator jit = edges.begin(); jit != edges.end(); ++jit){
        string l1 = (*jit)->getV1()->getLabel();
    string l2=(*jit)->getV2()->getLabel();
    if (l1 != it->first){cout << l1 << ", ";}
    if (l2 != it->first){cout << l2 << ", ";}
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
}

template <class T> 
bool isPath(T * t, string from, string to)
{
  Vertex * vfrom = t->getVertexWithLabel(from);
  Vertex * vto = t->getVertexWithLabel(to);

  if (vfrom == 0 || vto == 0) {
    return false;
  }

  if (from==to) {
    return true;
  }


  T g = *t;

  map<string, Vertex*> vertices = t->getVertices();
  vector<Edge *> edges = t->getEdges();

  vector<Vertex *> verticesToCheck;
  verticesToCheck.push_back(vfrom);
  vertices.erase(from);

  while (verticesToCheck.size() != 0){
    vector<Vertex *> destinations = t->whereCanIGo(verticesToCheck[0]);
      verticesToCheck.erase(verticesToCheck.begin());


      for (vector<Vertex *>::const_iterator it = destinations.begin(); it != destinations.end(); ++it) {
    //
    if (vertices.find((*it)->getLabel()) != vertices.end()) {
      if ((*it)->getLabel()==to) {
        return true;
      }
      verticesToCheck.push_back((*it));
      vertices.erase((*it)->getLabel());
    }
      }
  }
  return false;
}




int main(){
  UnDirectedGraph g;
  g.addVertex("v1");
  g.addVertex("v2");
  g.addVertex("v3");
  g.addEdge(1,"v1","v2");
  g.addEdge(1,"v2","v3");
  cout << isPath(&g,"v1","v3");
  cout << isPath(&g, "v2","v3");
  cout << isPath(&g,"v3","v2");
  cout << isPath(&g,"v3","v1");
  cout << isPath(&g,"v3","v3");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers!

Comment: Can you use C++11? I can see a few places where it could simplify your code quite a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should avoid `using namespace`, specially in a header file. Doing so exposes all of the contents of a namespace to the global scope. That defeats the purpose of a namespace, which is allowing for potentially colliding names to coexist. [Read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more details.
2. Pass complex objects by *const reference* when a copy is not needed. In C++, a function such as `void foo(std::string bar);` takes `bar` "by value", meaning that the `bar` string is copied into the function. The default in C++ is always a copy, even for object instances. When your methods/functions are only inspecting a parameter and that parameter is not a native type like `int`, `float`, etc, you should pass the parameter by const reference to avoid an unnecessary copy. E.g.:

   ```
   void foo(const std::string & bar) { /* ... */ }
   //       ^^^^^             ^
   //       const         reference
   ```
3. Make sure to initialize data in constructors using the *constructor initialization list*. This will ensure that you initialize your member objects only once, by calling their own constructors:

   ```
   Vertex(string l)
       : label(l)
       , visited(false)
   { }
   ```

   Using the assignment operator (`=`) inside the constructor body might result in unnecessary work, since first the default constructor for the object will be called, then you'll init again with `operator =`.
4. Be more consistent and careful with indentation. I can spot several places where your are missing tabs or have uneven spacing. That makes your code look untidy. Also consider inserting a few blank lines to separate unrelated things. Your code is a bit too crammed for my eyes.
5. If you have access to **C++11**, there are a few nice improvements an cleanups you can do with it:

   - Use the [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) literal to replace the uncanny `0` and the old & ugly `NULL`.
   - Use [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) for type inference. It can greatly simplify long statements like this:

     > ```
     > vector<Edge *> edges = v->getEdges();
     > ```

     Rewrite as:

     ```
     auto edges = v->getEdges();
     ```
   - Use [range based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) in places like this:

     > ```
     > for (vector<Edge *>::const_iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); ++it) { /* ... */ }
     > ```

     Rewrite as:

     ```
     for (auto & edge : edges) { /* ... */ }
     ```

Answer (score 2):

As with many posts tonight, a few things directly jump out:

1. `using namespace std;` worries me. The std lib has functions declared such as `max`, `min`, `set`, `lower_bound` etc. By importing the whole namespace, you can (i.e., should) *never* use those function names.
2. If a member function (i.e., method) does not alter the state of a class, you should declare it as `const`. You have done this in some places, but not everywhere.
3. Your `addVertex` member function uses the `new` keyword. However, it stores the variable inside the class, but also returns it. Who is responsible for calling `delete`? Consider using an appropriate smart pointer from `<memory>`.
4. Your `Vertex` class can only store strings. Consider using templates so it could story any type.
5. Your code indention is broken (unless you meant to indent seemingly random).
6. `verticesToCheck.size() != 0` can be replaced with the more readable `!verticesToCheck.empty()`

Comment: `main` doesn't have to explicitly return zero: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18402953/1198654

Comment: I have removed the item concerning the return value of `main`.